# Eclipse Scout Log4j No appenders could be found for logger

Tags: log4j, appender, eclipse-scout

In scout eclipse application I try to configure Log4j.

When I start server I get :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I have file log4j.properties and I put it in folder witch is in class path.

[image]

Where do I need to put this file so that application can read from it ?

Marko

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue a few days ago. I also use maven. The warnings are thrown by an object which uses this logging dependencies. There are several ways to log.
For me it worked with adding following dependecies to my POM.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I witch POM file. I try to add this in server/pom.xml and it did't work

Comment: I only have one pom.xml. It defines your maven project. This is in the main folder of your project. Also project build and plugins are defined there.

Comment: I figure it out.  I need to add log4j.properties file in scout backend and not in server. I need your solution to configure hibernate.